# Pass parameter to method gives "Cannot access method on a namespace"

Tags: c#

I am trying to use this method but I am confused about what/how to pass the parameter to it.

```
void SaveReport(Telerik.Reporting.Report report, string fileName)
{
    ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
    Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = 
        new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
    instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = report;
    RenderingResult result = 
        reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, null);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

I have tried to pass the name of the report I need to export, which is in a library in this way:

2nd Modification

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = "SS";
    var report = BOMreports.Report321();
    SaveReport(report, fileName );
}
```

But I keep getting the error "cannot access method on a namespace" on the var report.
I do I solve this?

Comment: What is BOMReports? A class or a namespace?

Comment: It is a class which contains several reports.

Comment: Why are the arguments to `SaveReport` are in the wrong order? In method signature it's `report, fileName` but when invoked you're passing `fileName, report`.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the error from that line? Try `var report = BOMReports.Report321(); SaveReport(filename, report);` on two lines. See which line gets the error.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry I meesed up a bit in the code I posted. However, I have updated now the code in my question but still I get the same error on the var report "cannot access method on a name space"

Comment: @haim770, thanks for highliting the order which I have now sorted out but still giving same problem on the var report

Comment: Show `BOMreports` code.

Comment: @haim770 thats a compiled class library in the bin (Dll) which is working correctly since it is also used in other methods. The funny thing is that when I start writing the name of the assembly "BOMreport." it appear in light blue. As soon as I add the report name "Report321" it became balck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a conflict in the `BOMreports` class and a name space with the same name. And since your namespace is in the same assembly as your code and the class is in another assembly, the compiler refers to it when you use the name in your code. Try to access the class with its fully identifier as:

```
namespace.BOMreports.Report321();
```

Another thing, make sure `Report321` is a static method that returns an object of `Telerik.Reporting.Report`.

> **Addition**

If `Report321` is a class in `BOMreports`, the you are doing it wrong. What you need to do is to instantiate it as the following:

```
var report = new BOMreports.Report321();
```

Comment: I investigated your hint but unless I am missing something from your answer, there are no conflicts in such DLL. The namespace is BOMreports and the name of the file in such name space is a class "Report321" which is working fine in several other context.

Comment: @Nullbyte So Report321 is not a method ?

Comment: No, BOMreports is a class library containg several classes of which Report321 is one of these.

Comment: You are a star! That was the problem. with your updated answer the problem is solved.

Comment: @Nullbyte I am not a star :p I guess you need some coffee. That's all :D